# Android Market: Application not visible on some Devices

Tags: android, permissions, google-play

i have written an application that needs to process outgoing calls. Everything works fine, the application has already a few hundred downloads, but now i get feedback from people who would like to download it, yet cannot find it.

I have done some tests and have found that the permission "PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" seems to be responsible for this. If i include it in an app, people with branded phones (at least in Germany) cannot find it, as soon as i remove this permission, everything is fine (when i re-insert it again, the app vanishes again)

The weird thing is, that those users can see other apps which use this permission in the market. I have compared my manifest file to outputs from other manifest files and cannot understand why it doesn't work.

Here is the manifest file for a test application i wrote to test the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.eventkontor.marketavailabilitytest" 
    android:versionName="1.2"
android:versionCode="3" 
    android:installLocation="auto">

<application 
         android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
         android:label="@string/app_name">

    <activity android:name=".showMain" 
                android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"
        android:targetSdkVersion="4" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>

<supports-screens android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true" android:largeScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="false"></supports-screens>

</manifest>
```

Does anyone have an idea what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Dontae's response in the [Android Market help forum thread](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?tid=2156a1d8ddb8ba47),

> Hi All,
>
> Our team is hard at work investigating this issue. We hope to have an update available to share soon.
>
> Thanks for your reports and your patience.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a general problem at the moment:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?tid=2156a1d8ddb8ba47&hl=en